# Printing URLs with fmt.Printf behaves weirdly

Tags: url, go

If i save the url in the database as

https://xxx.amazonaws.com/sub%2Fsub1/1495771021869-3sx5ims88vu-12f63aaa7d278435e1800486b31f9cc7/xxx.jpg

the http.ResponseWriter returns in the following format

https://xxx.amazonaws.com/sub!F(MISSING)sub1/1495771021869-3sx5ims88vu-12f63aaa7d278435e1800486b31f9cc7/xxx.jpg

in the above url you can see %2F is replaced with !F(MISSING)

can some one help to resolve this

the following is the code snippet
``  rs.WriteHeader(retObj.HttpStatus)

```
jsonStr, res := ConvObjectToJSON(retObj)
if res != nil {
    Logger(ctx, cnst.LogError, "In writeReturnError error in ConvObjectToJSON: %v Original object:%v",
        res.GetMessageWDetails(), retObj)
    rs.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}

var consoleLog *log.Logger = log.New(os.Stdout, cnst.LogPrefix, log.Ldate|log.Ltime)
consoleLog.Print(jsonStr)

cnt, err := fmt.Fprintf(rs, jsonStr)
if nil == err && 0 < cnt {
    rs.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
} else {
    Logger(ctx, cnst.LogError, "In writeReturnError error in fmt.Fprintf: %v Original JSON:%v",
        err.Error(), jsonStr)
    rs.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
}
```

``

I have a doubt with fmt.Fprintf

Comment: please paste the snippet where you are using it ?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with a Printf statement. Run go vet.

Comment: @RahulKamboj , please check the updated question

Comment: @Peter , I too have a doubt wit Fprintf

Comment: Just do not use Fprint**f**. What do you expect Fprint**f** to do? Or use Fprintf(rs, "%s", whatever") if you cannot tolerate the newline from Fprintln.

Comment: @Volker, Thank you for your suggestion , Fprintf(rs, "%s", whatever") Works fine

Comment: `Fprintf(rs, "%s", whatever")` is slower than `Fprint(rs, whatever)`. It has to parse the format first, do some string calculations and then it can finally write it to the writer.

Comment: Go has protected your application from being exploited by malicious input. This is why MISSING appears there. Always use a format string with `fmt.Fprintf()`, or if you don't really need to format anything, use `fmt.Fprint()` instead.

Answer (score 5):

As also mentioned in the comments: your problem is that Fprintf uses second parameter as a format interpreting every % as an indicator it should insert a variable there. In your string there is a % sign but you are not providing any arguments to insert. So it writings `MISSING`.

Since you do not want to format anything (it seems) just use this instead:

```
cnt, err := fmt.Fprint(rs, jsonStr)
```

Comment: @tehspinx, Thank you for the answer and i replaced the the Fprintf function to accept one more argument %s